# Micro template with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested-loops

I am trying to incorporate a micro template into a plugin I am building. I have gotten everything good and all, but I am having issues when it comes to the nested array in the data. Thank you very much in advance for your help. Here is the stripped code:

```
var locations = [{
            "name": "Disneyland California",
            "address": "1313 North Harbor Boulevard"
        },
        {
            "name": "Walt Disney World Resort",
            "address": "1503 Live Oak Ln"
        }],

        tmplData = [{
                    location: locations[0],
                    foo: "bar"
                }],

        template = "Shipping From:<br><b>{{location.name}}, {{foo}}",
        attachTemplateToData;

        attachTemplateToData = function(template, data) {
            var i = 0,
                len = data.length,
                fragment = '';
            function replace(obj) {
                var t, key, reg;
                for (key in obj) {
                    reg = new RegExp('{{' + key + '}}', 'ig');
                    t = (t || template).replace(reg, obj[key]);
                }       
                return t;
            }
            for (; i < data.length; i++) {
                fragment += replace(data[i]);
            }   
            console.log(fragment);
        };  
        attachTemplateToData(template, tmplData);
```

Logs:

```
bar,{{location.name}}
```

As you can see in the console.log that 'foo' comes out just fine, but I also need to get the 'location.name' ("Disneyland California") to render as well. I know its going to be a nested loop, but I cannot for the life of me figure out the syntax. BTW, the templating solution came from here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-makeshift-javascript-templating-solution/
Thanks!

EDIT:::
I am looking to make ANY property of the locations object able to be put into the template. So for instance if the user decided they want to add locations.city or locations.foo to the array, then in the template, they would just have to go {{location.city}} or {{location.foo}}. 
I HAVE been able to achieve this through the use of jQuery's tmpl plugin, but I don't need all of what that has to offer. I would like a VERY stripped version like I have, to only deal with the said instances. Here is what I did with the tmpl plugin (which works):

```
tmplData = [{
                    locations: settings.locations[i]
                }];

            var tmplMarkup = "Shipping From:<br><b>${locations.name}, ${locations.city}, ${locations.state}</b>";
            $.template("deTemplate", tmplMarkup);
            $.tmpl("deTemplate", tmplData).appendTo("#deResults");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your input *vittore*, I have finally figured out the code. Here is the extra if statement and regEx that I needed to have, also I found that I need the .hasOwnProperty function in there too:

```
for(subKey in obj[key]){
                        if (obj[key].hasOwnProperty(subKey)) {
                            reg = new RegExp('{{'+key+'.'+subKey+'}}');
                            t = (t || template).replace(reg, obj[key][subKey]);
                        }
                    }
```

Here is the completed code:

```
var locations = [{
        "name": "Disneyland California",
        "address": "1313 North Harbor Boulevard"
    },
    {
        "name": "Walt Disney World Resort",
        "address": "1503 Live Oak Ln"
    }],

    tmplData = [{
                location: locations[1],
                foo: "bar"
            }],

    template = "Shipping From:<br><b>{{location.address}}, {{foo}}",
    attachTemplateToData;

    attachTemplateToData = function(template, data) {
        var i = 0,
            j = 0,
            len = data.length,
            fragment = '';
        function replace(obj) {
            var t, key, subKey, subSubKey, reg;
            for (key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    reg = new RegExp('{{' + key + '}}', 'ig');
                    t = (t || template).replace(reg, obj[key]);
                    for(subKey in obj[key]){
                        if (obj[key].hasOwnProperty(subKey)) {
                            reg = new RegExp('{{' + key + '.' + subKey + '}}','ig');
                            t = (t || template).replace(reg, obj[key][subKey]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }       
            return t;
        }
        for (; i < data.length; i++) {
            fragment += replace(data[i]);
        }   
        console.log(fragment);
    };  
    attachTemplateToData(template, tmplData);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of this:

```
    var locations = [{
        "name": "Disneyland California",
        "address": "1313 North Harbor Boulevard"
    },
    {
        "name": "Walt Disney World Resort",
        "address": "1503 Live Oak Ln"
    }],

    tmplData = [{
                location: locations[0],
                foo: "bar"
            }],

    template = "Shipping From:<br><b>{{location.name}}, {{foo}}",
    attachTemplateToData;
```

Try this:

```
    var locations = [{
        name: "Disneyland California",
        address: "1313 North Harbor Boulevard"
    },
    {
        name: "Walt Disney World Resort",
        address: "1503 Live Oak Ln"
    }],

    tmplData = [{
                location: locations[0].name,
                foo: "bar"
            }],

    template = "Shipping From:<br><b>{{location}}, {{foo}}",
    attachTemplateToData;
```

Really it is just the .name needs to be about 4 lines up!  :)

Comment: you loose the idea behind templating that way, as you will need to hardcode every nested property like that.

Comment: You are right.  Having re-read the question and original example the answer is much simpler.  I have adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Tims, I already figured I could do this, and I guess I didn't specify in the question that I really would like for the 'user' to be able to not only add custom properties to the locations object, but also be able to call them up with the template function. For instance, lets say someone wanted to add a 'city' to both of the locations. I would would like for them to specify {{locations.city}} in the template, and without me knowing what property they added, it would just work. ie: {{locations.foo}}

I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: also FYI: my initial idea was to use jQuerys tmpl plugin and it worked exactly how I wanted. I am looking to remove this dependency for not only does the user have to remember to include that extra script, but also the tmpl plugin has SO much more that I am not considering using. Thanks again!

tmplData = [{
                        locations: locations[i],
                    }];

                var tmplMarkup = "Shipping From:${locations.name}, ${locations.city}";
                $.template("deTemplate", tmplMarkup);
                $.tmpl("deTemplate", tmplData).appendTo("#deResults");

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to change template recognition to match not only `{{prop}}` in your matching code , but also `{{prop.something}}`

you can do this adding another `if` statement with new regexp.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, except, I really am not sure how to go about this. If you have an example, I would be more than appreciative. I will continue to work on it from your explanation. Thanks!